# Make a button completely fill a framelayout

Tags: android, xml

**EDIT: My main goal is to have the button have white behind it, so it looks like a white background behind the button**

I can't seem to make a button completely fill a FrameLayout.

Even after setting the padding of the encapsulating FrameLayout to 0dp, (and I've even tried negative dp values), the button has a white border around it around 2dp thick.

The button does not totally fill up the FrameLayout as it should.

Code:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:padding="0dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus"
        android:hint="Create List"
        android:text="@string/lists_create" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The `FrameLayout` wraps around its child and the child view (button) is "matching" its parent. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to have it so that the FrameLayout has no padding inside it; right now, the button has noticeable padding around it which is inside the FrameLayout

Comment: Also, see edit in my question

Comment: Does the padding still remain if you remove the `drawableLeft`?

Comment: i have answered it , check that out

Comment: gunar, the padding still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may write the  code like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But I need a drawableLeft

Comment: dude,i checked it and posted ,don't tell me that its not working

Comment: But the FrameLayout needs to have a layout_width and layout_height of wrap_content. When I use your code, the button fills the whole screen.

Comment: dude , do one thing , keep the values of width,height in the frame layout, so according to the above code, the button fills the layout,since the layout is not occupying the entire screen,you may achieve the feet you desired , and ping me if it's working